# How to preview code attachments in Outlook?

Tags: email, outlook, syntax-highlighting, attachment, preview

I frequently sent or receive mail with source code attachments (.c, .cpp, .h, .js, etc). It would be easier if I could preview these files in Outlook, so I do not need to open in another application.
Preferably, the preview would include syntax highlighting, similar to Visual Studio.
Is there a Visual Studio preview plugin for Outlook?

I use Visual Studio 2010 pro and MS Office 2007 Pro+

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have (2) options here - you can roll your own or leverage an existing preview handler.

#### Existing Preview Handlers

[Windows Preview Handler Pack](http://previewhandlers.codeplex.com/): handles aspx, cs, css, js, sql, vb, etc.

---

#### Custom Preview Handlers

You should checkout the [Preview Handler Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776867.aspx) used by both Windows Shell and Office Outlook. There is a great walkthrough and sample code for building managed previewers in the January 2007 edition of [MSDN magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/msdn-magazine-issues).

Channel9 has a [video presentation describing the managed preview handler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DanielMoth/Managed-Preview-Handler-Framework-for-Vista-and-Outlook).

The [Preview Handler Editor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/12/14/preview-handler-association-editor.aspx) will show you what extensions are associated to what previewers.

[Preview Handler Registry Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969369.aspx) describes the registry key configuration used when looking for preview handlers.

Once you have the hook for the previewer in place - it would be up to you how you handle syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: I would like to extend the existing preview handler to show .out files as text. The same as is done for .log files. Can I tweak a registry entry somewhere to extend the preview file extension types?

Comment: I managed it by creating a key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.out` then by giving the `(Default) REG_SZ` a value of `txtfile`.

Comment: VS Code has [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73771) for preview handler. [delphi-preview-handler](https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-preview-handler) is opensource but unmaintained circa 2017. SmartFTP is bundled with a [Source Code Preview](https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/client/features/sourcepreview) handler that handles a number of modern languages; is a paid option.

Comment: @mrswadge, why you don't write an answer, you will get votes up, thank u